# add interactivity checkbox missing in excel 2010

Tags: html, excel, publish, office-2010

I'm trying to publish an excel file to the web and I want this file to be interactive for everyone.

After searching Google I saw that in the old office you could do it by enabling the **"add interactivity"** checkbox that is now missing in office 2010.

does anyone know how I can make my published excel file (now *.htm) be changed by any user through his Web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the capability of publishing interactive web pages was removed after Excel 2007. You will not be able to accomplish this using Excel 2010.

Have a look [here](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T000186_Generating_a_Web_Page.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes,
I saw that page. is there any other way to Accomplish what I want?

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan Using Excel 2010, it's a no. However, if you can get your hands on Excel 2007, then you can go ahead with the normal procedure.

Comment: so my last question will be: if I would get 2007 but the other users will have Excel 2010 it will still work, yes?